# Buildings not respecting CenterX/Y

Tags: 3dsmax, ryzom

I have been trying to place a building using the guide at http://dev.ryzom.com/projects/ryzom/wiki/Adding_Buildings however the buildings that I place I am unable to move the x/y coordinates only the zone works ie 88_BY changed to 88_BZ does move the building one zone

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you cant use object reference with the 3ds max plugin, use a scene reference instead.